# Error with Puppeteer when using Parcel bundler

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer, parcel

I have a problem with a script containing Puppeeter when I run it with Parcel. When I launched it with command line, without building with Parcel, it works fine.

My first error was the message : `Uncaught SyntaxError:missing = in const declaration`

It appears because the variable `const PUPPETEER_EXPERIMENTAL_CHROMIUM_MAC_ARM;` was not initialized in the index.87e9977b.js file in the dist folder created by Parcel.

So I tried to add the variable to my environment variables, and to npm config file, but it didn't worked, so I just commented the line.

After that I had many other errors showing as in the picture below.
[image]

Here is the code of my script **WebScrapperPuppeteer.ts**. It works when not using Parcel.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

async function main(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://unsplash.com/t/animals", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    //await page.waitFor(5000);
    await page.screenshot({path:'test.png'});
    let images = await page.evaluate(()=> {
        let img = Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll("img.YVj9w")
            ).map((image) => image.getAttribute("src"));
        return img;
    });

    console.log(images);
    await browser.close();
}

main();
```

I don't want to change Parcel if possible, because for everything else it is very convenient.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Parcel is used to build packages for the browser. You can't use `puppeteer` in the browser